# use defined CASE further in the same SELECT as variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, case

I have a `SELECT` statement in which I defined `CASE` expression which I'm using in another calculations within the same `SELECT`. However it's quite big CASE so I don't want to copy it all the time. Is it possible to define it as variable and then use only name of the variable in my calculations?

E.g.:

```
CASE WHEN xxxx END AS - define it as @test
then use it for example in WHERE part - WHEN @test='X'
```

is it possible? thanks

Comment: You may want to look at a _common table expression_ (CTE). It's a handy way to break a single query into what looks like reasonable steps building on one another. The query optimizer still processes it as a single query so the performance needn't suffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can AND doing so has great performance benefits. Consider these the following sample data and query.

```
-- Sample data
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#sometable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #sometable;
CREATE TABLE #sometable(someid int identity, somevalue decimal(10,2));
INSERT #sometable(somevalue) VALUES (100),(1050),(5006),(111),(4);

-- Query:
DECLARE @var1 int = 100, @var2 int = 50, @var3 int = 900, @topPct tinyint = 90;

SELECT TOP (@topPct) PERCENT
  someid,
  somevalue,
  someCalc = 
      CASE WHEN @var3 < somevalue THEN (@var1/(@var2*2.00))+@var3 ELSE @var3+somevalue END,
  someRank = dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY
      CASE WHEN @var3 < somevalue THEN (@var1/(@var2*2.00))+@var3 ELSE @var3+somevalue END)
FROM #sometable
WHERE CASE WHEN @var3 < somevalue THEN (@var1/(@var2*2.00))+@var3 ELSE @var3+somevalue END
  BETWEEN 900 AND 2000
ORDER BY -- simulate another event that causes a sort
      CASE WHEN @var3 < somevalue THEN (@var1/(@var2*2.00))+@var3 ELSE @var3+somevalue END;
```

As mentioned, you could you CROSS APPLY like so:

```
-- Improved
SELECT TOP (@topPct) PERCENT 
  s.someid, s.somevalue, someCalc=iTVF.result, someRank=DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY iTVF.result)
FROM        #sometable AS s
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CASE WHEN @var3 < somevalue THEN (@var1/(@var2*2.00))+@var3
            ELSE @var3+somevalue END)) AS iTVF(result)
WHERE iTVF.result BETWEEN 900 and 2000
ORDER BY iTVF.result;
```

Notice how I have replaced all references of the CASE statement with **itvf.result**. The code is much cleaner. The other benefit is the execution plan. Using CROSS APPLY in this way prevents the optimizer from performing the same calculation twice.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want something like that :

```
select *
from . . .  cross apply
    ( values (case when . . .
                   then . . . 
                   else . . .
              end) 
    ) tt (test)
where tt.test = 'X'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your query inside a sub-query and place the SELECT and WHERE clauses outside it:

```
SELECT a, b, c, test
FROM (
    SELECT a, b, c, CASE
        WHEN ...
        WHEN ...
    END AS test
    FROM ...
) AS sq
WHERE sq.test = 'something'
```

Ideally you should avoid case inside where clause.